# WKWebView Not Opening Camera And Gallery Using Image Capture SDK

Tags: swift, xcode, webview, wkwebview, image-capture

I have problem with using identity service with WkWebView. When I need to open my camera and see permission for opening camera I see error. Also I add permissions to camera and gallery in info.plist and in configuration of webview allow allowsInlineMediaPlayback, but still it doesn't work.[image: Image of Image Capture SDK]

Answer (score 1):

i think you deal with this problem just because you don't wrote this
**SecTrustSetExceptions** for that particular url. As there is some conflict with its signing identity and your WKWebView.

As other variant you can just run pod install and **pod repo update**